# Align div/span to top left of table cell

Tags: html, css, css-position, html-table, vertical-alignment

I have a table that represents a calendar month. That is, each row is a week, and each cell is a day. I'd like to display the date number in the top left of each cell, like it is on most calendars (e.g., [here](http://calendars.vertex42.com/2013/July-2013-calendar.png)), while still allowing other content, of an arbitrary number of words/lines, to be in the cell, but I can't get it to align. Any ideas on some CSS (or changes to the HTML structure, if needed) that can make this work? Here's [some example code](http://cssdesk.com/LHFub).

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily do this by setting the parent element (the `td`) with a `position:relative` which causes the child elements to be absolutely positioned [relative to the element in question](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/), because any absolutely positioned element is [positioned according to it's closest positioned - absolute, relative, or fixed - parent](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#relative-positioning). As correctly noted by `Gaby aka G. Petrioli` the spec I linked to does not define behavior of how `table-cells` should funciton when set to `position:relative` however all browser implementations do consistently implement this none the less and in a case like this I believe it appropriate to use this property.

So all you need in the end is have `.day` be `position:relative` and `.date_num_container` be set to `position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px;` and it starts working as you can see here:
http://cssdesk.com/ERpLC

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
td.day {position: relative;}
.date_num_container {position:absolute; top:0; left:0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for absolute positioning

```
td.day
{
    height:15%;
    width:14%;
    background:#ccc;
    padding:0;
    vertical-align:top;
}

div.date_num_container{
  text-align:center;
}
```

**Demo at** http://cssdesk.com/WMFrA

Comment: Please note that now the cell content got dispositioned as well, whereas with absolute positioning you still have full control over all the different content.

Comment: @DavidMulder you cannot set relative position on table cells.. See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#choose-position

Comment: Just to be symantically correct, you should not set relative position on table cells, you still can and note that the implementation across browsers is consistent despite not being in the spec.

Comment: @DavidMulder actually it is not.. in FF and Safari (*for windows*) your code does not work.. all numbers go to top/left of the screen.. not in their respective `td` elements..

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the need for absolute positionning in your case.
You can take it simple:

```
div.date_num_container {
height:100%;
//remove absolute positionning
}

.other_stuff {
margin-top:25px;
text-align:center
}
```